# Execute Script available on remote machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, zsh

I am trying to execute a script available on remote machine using `ssh`. The output differ if it is run from client via ssh or run after ssh into the server.

The script will trim a file.

```
tail -n 100 users.txt > temp.txt
rm users.txt
mv temp.txt users.txt
echo $(wc -l users.txt)
echo Done
```

On running from **client side** :

```
client@client_mac $ ssh user@server_mac '~/path_to_script/demo_script.sh'
```

Output :

```
0 users.txt
Done
```

while after ssh'ing at **server side** :

```
client@client_mac $ ssh user@server_mac
user@server_mac $ cd ~/path_to_script/
user@server_mac $ ./demo_script.sh
```

Output :

```
100 users.txt
Done
```

How do we execute a script that is available on remote machine  ? Is the syntax different ?

Comment: You should get the same result. I don't think it's relevant, but `wc -l users.txt` is sufficient; you don't need to call it in a command substitution to pass to `echo`.

Comment: Actually, the working directory in the first example is `~`, not `~/path_to_script`, so you appear to be getting the sizes of two different files, `~/users.txt` and `~/path_to_script/users.txt`.

Comment: Yes it was an issue with current working directory. Works correctly after modifying `demo_script.sh` to take `~/path_to_script/users.txt` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script always looks for `users.txt` in the current working directory.

In the first example, the current working directory is your home directory; that's why you have to run the script with `~/path_to_script/demo_script.sh` rather than `./demo_script.sh`. As such, you are getting the line count of `~/users.txt` in your output.

In the second example, you *change* the working directory from `~` to `~/path_to_script` before executing the script, so the output contains the line count of `~/path_to_script/users.txt`.